# In Carla Simulator I want to import a Map which I have created in RoadRunner

Tags: matlab, import, carla, roadrunner

I have created a map in roadrunner, I have the option of
`add/import`
but when I added the map it shows
`Failed for many operations`
I also checked the file format which it needs to be imported.

If anyone have any detailed steps to import a manually made map into carla world be a help.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have built CARLA from source, then it is quite straightforward:

https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuto_M_add_map_source/

If you have the packaged version,

https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuto_M_add_map_package/

I assume that you have the packaged version, in which case you need to run a Docker image.